# Get specific element from array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Basically I am trying to return an element from an 2d array in java. I have created a separate Matrix class and inside the class I want to write a get_element method which would take as input the coordinates of the element I want from the matrix and the matrix itself, however I am not sure how to do this.

```
public static double get_element(Matrix A, double m , double n)
{  
    for(int i=0;i<A.rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<A.cols;j++)
           return A.data[m][n];


}
```

This is how my code look right now. And I get an error that says lossy conversion between double and int.

Comment: Why are you passing/expecting indexes as `double`s? They should be `int`.

Comment: The indices of an array are integers, not doubles. Use the appropriate type.

Comment: You should never use doubles as indexes for arrays, pass in integers instead. You can't access position [0.5]. The compiler is likely complaining because it needs to convert them to integers in order to use them as the index.

Comment: As an aside: follow naming conventions: the method should be named `getElement`, and the matrix should be named `a` (or, even better, a more descriptive name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the loop. Also, you need to convert the double to `int`

```
return A.data[(int) m][(int) n];
```

Alternatively (better), you change the method signature:

```
public static double get_element(Matrix A, int m , int n) {  
    return A.data[m][n];
}
```