# How to use one file from list of files

Tags: java, file, csv

```
File folder = new File("C:/Path/Dir");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();


        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                String csvFile = file.getName();
                System.out.println(csvFile);
            }
        }

Output:
1.csv
2.csv
3.csv
```

There is 3 files in my Dir so after i get all 3 of them how can i use the first one in my file reader:

```
 //File reader
            Path path = Paths.get(csvFile);
            int lineCount = (int) Files.lines(path).count();
```

Comment: `listOfFiles` is an array ... so, how can you access the first element of an array? That is basic Java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get specific element from array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226963/get-specific-element-from-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

If you are specific to 1st file only then just use `listOfFiles[0].getName()` to get fileName.

If you are to going to take path of a file that satisfy specific condition then you can use like below :

```
File folder = new File("C:/Path/Dir");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

String csvFile = null;
for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    if (file.isFile() && <condition>) {
       csvFile = file.getName();
       System.out.println(csvFile);
       break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`listOfFiles[0]` should get you the first element.

Please read some tutorials on java arrays :
https://www.javatpoint.com/array-in-java

Answer (score 0):

There:

```
File folder = new File("C:/Path/Dir");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();


for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        String csvFile = file.getName();
        System.out.println(csvFile);

        // Reader (for all files)
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        } catch (IOException e) { /* TODO */ }

        // Line count (for all files)
        int lineCount = (int) Files.lines(file.toPath()).count();
    }
}

// Reader (for first file)
File firstFile = listOfFiles[0];

try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
} catch (IOException e) { /* TODO */ }

// Line count (for first file)
int lineCount = (int) Files.lines(firstFile.toPath()).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
  if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
    System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
  } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
  }
}
```

then i use 
listOfFiles[i] in my file reader

Sorry for been dump for a while )

Answer (score 0):

When you are only interested in files (not directories or whatever) you can already specify this criteria in your File.listFiles call:

```
    File[] files=new File("c:/tmp").listFiles(new FileFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isFile();
        }
    });
```

Or with java 8 Lambdas

```
    File[] files=new File("c:/tmp").listFiles((f)->{return f.isFile();});
```

In the list of files you can pick the first one as you would do to pick the first element of an array:

```
    System.out.println("First file:"+(files.length>0?files[0]:" no files"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you have all files in an array of the File as

```
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

So you can directly access the first file by index (index starts with 0) as follows

```
Path path = Paths.get(listOfFiles[0].getName());
int lineCount = (int) Files.lines(path).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out two thing:first read only file not folder;second which file is the fisrt file.The follow code assume you want read file and get first file by file name in dictionary order:

```
private static void readFirstFile(String path) throws Exception {
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] files = folder.listFiles(File::isFile);
    if (null == files || files.length < 3) {
        return;
    }
    Arrays.sort(files, Comparator.comparing(File::getName));
    List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(files[0], "UTF-8");
    lines.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```